# How to specify the visible range of a SDL renderer window

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to make a SDL window, the problem is that I only need a specific range of the window to be generally visible, like from 50 to 100 in x direction and 70 to 150 in y. Imagine I want a window with width of 500 and height of 500, but I want to show the mentioned range of x and y (50 to 100 in x direction and 70 to 150 in y.) in this window:

[image: example image]
How should I specify that in my code. :

```
> if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
>         std::cout << "Error initializing SDL: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
>     }
>      SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("window",
>       SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
>       SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
>       SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H, -----> here I specify the width and height
>       SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
> 
>           SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
>           SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

Comment: Do you want to stretch the specified range to the full size of the window?

Comment: What do you want to show exactly? Do you want to hide the whole window except for that "range" (which just sounds like a rectangle to me, or a `SDL_Rect` if you prefer)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, exactly

Comment: [`SDL_RenderSetClipRect()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetClipRect)?

Comment: Can you provide a clear use case to that? As it sounds now, it is highly unusual case and I highly doubt it would be possible with SDL directly. But maybe that is not even a solution to your problem. So - what is your initial problem that you're trying to solve (i.e. where do you want to use that kind of window and why)?